# Are there uncountably many probability density functions?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, cardinals

Curious what the cardinality of the set of pdfs is. Does it change depending on whether they have infinite/finite support?

Edit: Sorry for the poor wording, I mean given a fixed support, what is the cardinality of the set of pdfs on that support?

Comment: I believe this is uncountable regardless. Take the uniform distribution with parameter $\theta$ defined by $U(0,\theta)$ where $\theta \in [0,1]$. Since $[0,1]$ is uncountable, so should the PDF, no?

Comment: I imagine the situation is "worse" with infinite support.

Comment: Sorry, I should have probably been more clear - I meant more for a fixed support is it uncountable?

Comment: Same reasoning... take the normal distribution with fixed variance and mean ranging between 0 and 1. The interval is uncountable so the number of PDFs is uncountable.

Comment: @Gregory The more interesting question is, is the number of PDFs more than the number of reals? (The answer is yes, so the number of PDFs is more than just uncountable)

Comment: Oh wow duh yeah. Dunno what I was thinking, thanks!

Comment: @DonThousand yes, you are right of course.

Comment: @ Don Thousand will you please provide a link to that fact. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think DonThousand's claim is true. CDFs are right-continuous and therefore determined by their values on rational points (right?), so the set of all real-valued random variables has cardinaity $|\Bbb R^\Bbb Q|=|\Bbb R|$.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698864/why-does-the-number-of-possible-probability-distributions-have-the-cardinality-o/3698870).

Comment: @Karl Many PDFs have the same CDF...

Comment: Oh! How is that? Doesn't the CDF uniquely determine the distribution?